# Cloud Foundry and WinSCP

Tags: ssh-tunnel, cloud, winscp

What is the simplest way to access the Cloud Foundry application container using WinSCP?

The way I know, I need following steps:

1. Login / Target

   ```bsh
   cf login
   cf target -o app-org -s app-space
   ```
2. Retrieve and display the given app's guid

   ```bsh
   cf app pef-sso-server-dev --guid
   ```
3. Get a one time password for ssh clients

   ```bsh
   cf ssh-code
   ```
4. Establishing a connection

   - hostname: `<my-app>.<my-domain>`
   - port: `2222`
   - username: `cf:<app-guid>/<app-instance-index>@ssh.<my-domain>`
   - password: `<ssh-code>`

Could we just use [CF CLI](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org) to create [SSH tunnel](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/ssh.html) and connect WinSCP to local forwarded port without re-authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of `cf`, support the `ssh` command:

```
cf ssh MY-AWESOME-APP
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#ssh-command) for more details.

Comment: It has nothing to do with WinSCP.